# Is there a Sumologic handler for monolog?

Tags: php, logging, monolog, sumologic

I'm looking for a [Sumologic](https://www.sumologic.com/) handler for [monolog](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog). I could not find one using a Google search. The monolog [site](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog/wiki/Third-Party-Packages) does not mention such a thing. Before we write one ourselves, I wanted to check that one does not already exist.